# Not able to deploy dash application on Gunicorn

Tags: python-3.x, gunicorn, plotly-dash

I want to deploy a dash application on Gunicorn. But I am not able to do so. I see no errors appearing on the screen when I execute the `gunicorn <module_name>:<variable_name>`

Versions:

- gunicorn (20.0.4)
- dash (1.17.0)
- dash-core-components (1.13.0)
- dash-html-components (1.1.1)
- dash-renderer (1.8.3)
- dash-table (4.11.0)

my dash application, file name: `analyzer.py`

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd
import flask

<data_frame definitions>


app = dash.Dash()
server = app.server

<app.layout>

<Call backs>

## at the end

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

When I use the below command, I see no errors on the screen, but yet I can’t reach the application from the browser.

```
[user1@myHost]$ gunicorn analyzer:server -b:8000

[2021-04-16 16:57:58 +0200] [8334] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2021-04-16 16:57:58 +0200] [8334] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (8334)
[2021-04-16 16:57:58 +0200] [8334] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-04-16 16:57:58 +0200] [8345] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8345
```

I see that the port is listening, however, I am not able to open my dashboard on the server’s public IP and 0.0.0.0
The port 8000 is in listen mode

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN

gunicorn  13003     user1    5u  IPv4 49878669      0t0  TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)
gunicorn  13015     user1    5u  IPv4 49878669      0t0  TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)
```

Could you please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried changing the IP from 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yes I have tried that before posting it here. It did not work.

Comment: Hmm, can you access the swagger docs for the FastAPI deployment? Could you post the rest of your code?

Comment: I guess, the main part of the code that deals with deployment, deals with the definition of the "server" in application code. The rest of the code is basically the functional logic behind a scatter graph and an app.callback. 
Although it works fine on local, it is not working when I use gunicorn for deploying on Linux even after defining server = app.server and passing it in the gunicorn command line as `gunicorn analyzer:server`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a server is told to listen to `0.0.0.0`, that means "listen on all bound IP addresses". Browsers can use any IP address that is bound to that server to access it. The `127` family of addresses is one of the sets of addresses that is guaranteed to be bound to every machine.

That means you should be able to browse to `https://127.0.0.0:8000` to view the webapp. Also, `https://127.0.0.1:8000`, `https://127.0.1.0:8000`, `https://127.666.312.432:8000`, etc.

However, asking a web browser to visit `https://0.0.0.0` means "I do not know where I want to connect to" and always fails. That includes all ports, so attempting to browse to `https://0.0.0.0:8000` will always fail.

Comment: What I thought as well but wasn't entirely sure. Great complete answer.

Comment: Hey, if you like the answer, please upvote

Comment: I did before commenting ;-)

Comment: Thanks Mike. I did try with 127.0.0.1, I even tried with the public IP address of the server. But it did not work. Nothing seems to work. I then posted my question here. Could you guide me further.!!

Comment: Hey Mike, I added the port to `firewalld` and restarted the service. It worked. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Since I was not facing any error messages on terminal, I tried `wget` and found a `200 OK` response. This made it clear that I was not able to fetch my dashboard through the browser.
So I added the port to `firewalld` and restarted `firewalld`. The dashboard was accessible through the browser.

Thank you people, for your time.