# Running Dash on a public IP : werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not Found

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm trying to run a Dash app on a VM which is accessible using a public IP (behind a NAT).

Here is the basic Dash app:

```
from dash import Dash, html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_daq as daq
from dash import Input, Output, State, dcc
from flask import Flask, url_for
import os
import numpy as np

server = Flask(__name__)
server.config.update(
    SERVER_NAME=os.getenv("SERVER_NAME", "localhost:8080")
)
app = Dash(__name__,server=server, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP, \
dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div(children=[    html.H1(children='Test'),    html.Div(    '\
''        Built with Dash: A web application framework for Python.    ''')])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)
```

If I run the app with a `python test.py`, when I browse http://my_public_IP:8080, it returns: `werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not Found`

If I run the app with `gunicorn --workers 1 --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 test:server`, it returns a classic:
`The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.`

The following log are produced by gunicorn:

```
[2022-09-20 09:25:50 +0000] [62184] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-09-20 09:25:50 +0000] [62184] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (62184)
[2022-09-20 09:25:50 +0000] [62184] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-09-20 09:25:50 +0000] [62186] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 62186
/home/azure-vm-user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:2218: UserWarning: Current server name 'my_public_IP:8080' doesn't match configured server name 'localhost:8080'
  return self.url_map.bind_to_environ(
```

Thanks for your help. I've probably missed something simple here but can't find anything equivalent in SO except this post which doesn't solved my problem:
[Not able to deploy dash application on gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67138641/not-able-to-deploy-dash-application-on-gunicorn)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you completely omit the setting of the `SERVER_NAME` configuration variable?

Flask/Werkzeug does check if the `SERVER_NAME` you have set in the configuration of your application matches the `Host` part of the HTTP header sent to the application as part of the HTTP request. If it does not match you get the UserWarning message you have observed in the log and the `subdomain` URL part of the router is internally set to "<invalid>" which results into all routes intentionally returning 404 error.

See the following code excerpt from `werkzeug.routing.Map.bind_to_environ()`:

```
            if subdomain is None and not self.host_matching:
            cur_server_name = wsgi_server_name.split(".")
            real_server_name = server_name.split(".")
            offset = -len(real_server_name)

            if cur_server_name[offset:] != real_server_name:
                # This can happen even with valid configs if the server was
                # accessed directly by IP address under some situations.
                # Instead of raising an exception like in Werkzeug 0.7 or
                # earlier we go by an invalid subdomain which will result
                # in a 404 error on matching.
                warnings.warn(
                    f"Current server name {wsgi_server_name!r} doesn't match configured"
                    f" server name {server_name!r}",
                    stacklevel=2,
                )
                subdomain = "<invalid>"
            else:
                subdomain = ".".join(filter(None, cur_server_name[:offset]))
```

In your case you are binding the app server to listen on all available interfaces on the host using the `0.0.0.0` directive in
`app.run_server(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)`
If one of the interfaces matches the address `my_public_IP` your application should be accessible without any `SERVER_NAME` set and the router should be able to match the defined routes.